# Grails - getting values from a database

Tags: database, grails

In Grails I want to get back a list of invoices I have in a database. I then want to display these on a gsp for ones due in under 7 days. I know I have to write something in the Grails controller and then a gsp page.

What I placed in the Controller

```
def dueInvoices(){
        getDueInvoices = Invoices.getDueDate(dueDate)
        if(dueDate < 7)
        redirect(action: "list")
         [invoicesInstance: invoicesInstance]
    }
```

I then have a gsp page named dueInvoices with the following code

```
<g:each in="${dueInvoices}" var="p">
        <li>${p}</li>
        </g:each>
```

Comment: And see the getting started with grails book. It will help a lot for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

```
def dueInvoices(){
        def invoices = Invoices.findAllByDueDateLessThan(new Date() - 7)
        render(view: "list", model: [dueInvoices : invoices ])
}
```

Comment: This looks for an integer not a date so it returns an error. I take it I would need to grab today's date and pass it into the findAllByLessThan() method

Comment: Change it to `def invoices = Invoices.findAllByDueDatesLessThan(new Date() - 7)`.

Comment: ya.sorry.i forget is this date.now see updated code as said by grantmc